# How to call a Javascript function expression

Tags: javascript, function, expression

Can someone please help me understand how to call this JS function expression

```
var math = {
    'factorial': function factorial(n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: `math.factorial(n)`.

Comment: Indentation is so 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Should be self-evident:

```js
var math = 
{
    'factorial': function factorial(n) 
    {
        if (n <= 1)
          return 1;
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
};

var result = math.factorial(3);

// For the purposes of illustration, we will use document.write to output 
// the result. document.write is generally not a good idea, however!

document.write(result);
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the quotes around factorial are not necessary :)

Comment: That's the same code from the OP's question. The comment would be better there...